# AVD showing in console

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Good Day stackoverflow

When i try running my application in the AVD it gives the below error in the console :

```
[2014-02-24 06:39:35 - lib-c2callsdkres] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

[2014-02-24 07:44:37 - pull-to-refresh] Unable to resolve target 'android-16'

[2014-02-24 07:53:43 - pull-to-refresh] Unable to resolve target 'android-16'

[2014-02-24 11:13:41 - lib-c2callsdkres] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

[2014-02-24 11:44:07 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\user\workspace\SdkDemo\AndroidManifest.xml: The value of attribute "android:authorities" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

[2014-02-24 11:44:07 - SdkDemo] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

[2014-02-24 12:07:13 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper]

Parser exception for C:\Users\user\workspace\SdkDemo\AndroidManifest.xml: The value of attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

[2014-02-24 12:07:13 - SdkDemo] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

[2014-02-24 12:07:44 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] 

Parser exception for C:\Users\user\workspace\SdkDemo\AndroidManifest.xml: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "android:name".

[2014-02-24 12:07:44 - SdkDemo] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

[2014-02-24 12:25:33 - Scringo] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

[2014-02-24 13:00:55 - google-play-services_lib] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\user\workspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\jarlist.cache

[2014-02-24 13:00:55 - google-play-services_lib] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\user\workspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\jarlist.cache

[2014-02-24 13:01:13 - ScringoSample] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

[2014-02-24 13:01:15 - ScringoSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\user\workspace\ScringoSample\bin\jarlist.cache

[2014-02-24 13:01:16 - ScringoSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\user\workspace\ScringoSample\bin\jarlist.cache

[2014-02-24 13:01:16 - ScringoSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\user\workspace\ScringoSample\bin\jarlist.cache

[2014-02-24 13:01:16 - ScringoSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\user\workspace\ScringoSample\bin\jarlist.cache

[2014-02-24 15:01:35 - ScringoSample] ------------------------------

[2014-02-24 15:01:35 - ScringoSample] Android Launch!

[2014-02-24 15:01:35 - ScringoSample] adb is running normally.

[2014-02-24 15:01:36 - ScringoSample] Performing com.scringo.scringosample.MainActivity activity launch

[2014-02-24 15:01:37 - ScringoSample] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'nexus'

[2014-02-24 15:01:37 - ScringoSample] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'nexus'

Blockquote

[2014-02-24 15:02:19 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed

[2014-02-24 15:02:19 - Emulator] 

[2014-02-24 15:02:26 - ScringoSample] New emulator found: emulator-5554

[2014-02-24 15:02:26 - ScringoSample] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

[2014-02-24 15:09:04 - ScringoSample] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

[2014-02-24 15:09:04 - ScringoSample] Uploading ScringoSample.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2014-02-24 15:09:09 - ScringoSample] Installing ScringoSample.apk...

[2014-02-24 15:11:24 - ScringoSample] Failed to install ScringoSample.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

[2014-02-24 15:11:24 - ScringoSample] (null)

[2014-02-24 15:11:24 - ScringoSample] Launch canceled!
```

I will like to know the required solution

Thank you

Comment: I think its about Java compiler version. Downgrade it to 1.6 in project properties.

Comment: One thing more, in pull to refresh, change android version to what api version you have installed. Android 16 is not installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the android versions required in the manifest file.

Also right click it and go to Android Tools-> Fix project properties to fix java version.

When using a switch case with strings for example, that is not supported on android compared to the latest java versions.